# Excel get substring from nth position up to the end of string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So How to get substring from nth position up to the end of string?

Input at cell A1 `Name: Thomas B.`

Expected output: `Thomas B.`

I know some way to do it but I wonder if there are other elegant ways than them? (some kind of `=RIGHT(A1, -6)`....)

1. `=MID(A1, 6, 999999)`     //999999 looks not so good
2. `=MID(A1, 6, LEN(A1) - 5)`     //must calculate 2 times, first get len, then get substring, seems too much works?

Comment: You don't need to subtract 5 in the second example. However, I doubt very much if micro-optimisation of performance is an issue you need worry about.

Comment: Your `MID` formulae appear to contradict your title. Do you want to get the substring from the *n*th character from the beginning or the end of a string?

Comment: @Jerry nth from beginning of the string, get all character up to the end of string. I will try edit that title

Comment: @KenY-N Today I just face this problem, first I think `=RIGHT(A1, -6)` is ok, but it won't work so I search and from `MID` function I write those 2 formulas above. Wonder if there are other elegant ways to go. If I can't find one then I will use the `=MID(A1, 6, LEN(A1)). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## REPLACE

As Dominique already wrote:
'Why don't you just replace the first six characters by an empty string?'

> ```
> =REPLACE(A1,1,6,"")
> ```

I've done some time measuring, but the difference is less than a second at 50000 records (for `LEFT`, `MID`, `REPLACE` & `SUSTITUTE`). So I'm afraid **ELEGANCE** is all you're going to get.

### A Small Study

I created this study due to the fact that when you say from the n-th character, your `n`-th character is **7** (your `MID`-s are wrong), but you want to remove the first `n-1` (**6**) characters. So depending on how you formulate your question, you might have a different approach in `RIGHT` or `MID`, and you will remember `REPLACE` and `SUBSTITUTE` or you may not.

[image]

### Small Study Formulas for A1 (*) and B1 (#, ?, *)

**Get String From N-th Character to the End, e.g. 7**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(B1-1))
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-B1+1)
```

> ```
> =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)
> ```

```
=MID(A1,B1,LEN(A1)-(B1-1))
=MID(A1,B1,LEN(A1)-B1+1)
=MID(A1,B1,LEN(A1))
=MID(A1,7,LEN(A1)-6)
```

> ```
> =MID(A1,7,LEN(A1))
> ```

**Remove N First Characters of a String, e.g. 6**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-B1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)
=MID(A1,B1+1,LEN(A1)-B1)
=MID(A1,B1+1,LEN(A1))
=MID(A1,7,LEN(A1)-6)
=MID(A1,7,LEN(A1))
```

**Get String After a Character e.g. " "**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND(B1,A1)))
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND(" ",A1)))
=MID(A1,FIND(B1,A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(B1,A1))
=MID(A1,FIND(B1,A1)+1,LEN(A1))
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

**Get String After a String e.g. ": "**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND(B1,A1)+LEN(B1))+1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(B1,A1)-LEN(B1)+1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(": ",A1)-LEN(": ")+1)
=MID(A1,FIND(B1,A1)+LEN(B1),LEN(A1)-(FIND(B1,A1)+LEN(B1))+1)
=MID(A1,FIND(B1,A1)+LEN(B1),LEN(A1)-FIND(B1,A1)-LEN(B1)+1)
=MID(A1,FIND(B1,A1)+LEN(B1),LEN(A1))
=MID(A1,FIND(": ",A1)+LEN(": "),LEN(A1)-FIND(": ",A1)-LEN(": ")+1)
=MID(A1,FIND(": ",A1)+LEN(": "),LEN(A1))
```

**Back to Remove N First Characters of a String, e.g. 6**

> ```
> =SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,6),"",1)
>
> =REPLACE(A1,1,6,"")
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I faced that problem yesterday, and find some trouble describe it clearly in my question. As I'm not used to excel formula, so I end up finding those above ways to do it. For your "small study", IMO they all could  apply to my problem. And for my specific case, I think `=REPLACE(A1,1,6,"")` should be the most elegant one

Answer (score 4):

Well, both of your methods already work, but you could also use this one:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)
```

(you nearly had this one in your own question)

or this one:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,100))
```

(the FIND() function returns the numeric position of a search string, so is great for doing dynamic substrings)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the `FIND()` function with dynamic for `Name: `, `Name :`, `name: `, `Full name:`....

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just replace the first six characters by an empty string?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;LEFT(A1;6);"";1)
```

Comment: This is one nice way if improved to `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, LEFT(A1;6), "", 1)` or `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "Name: ", "", 1)` in case 6 first chars is fixed

Comment: What about asdfghJKLasdfgh? It will give back JKL.

Comment: @z32a7ul: you're right. I've edited my answer as mentioned by Pham (added the "1" at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you create a constant with the value 2^31-1 (=2147483647), which is the maximum signed integer value on 32-bit systems, and you give it a nice name, like MaxInt, then your first formula will be efficient and nice looking, too:

```
=MID(A1, 6, MaxInt)
```

You can add the Name with Ctrl+F3. If you are interested in fast calculations, giving it as 2147483647 rather than 2^31-1 may have some (very little) advantage.